# Sql error at Login Page

Tags: penetration-test, sql-injection, burp-suite

I am testing an application where I am getting this SQL error message:

```
RT_userName :test'; RT_userPassword fg Exceptionjava.sql.SQLException: Invalid SQL statement or JDBC escape, terminating ''' not found.
```

I am capturing the request in Burp but it is not showing my username and password; all the data is encrypted.

Any suggestions on how to exploit SQL injection?

Comment: Firstly, do you have permission to test the application? Can you provide more information, such as what code you injected?

Comment: Why do you think that there is a SQLi vulnerability? We can't possibly help without a LOT more data on the target.

Comment: i have permission to test the application,i am testing in UAT environment,at the login page i am getting sql errror,as my understanding it is error based sql injection,but i am getting the errors like this RT_userName :select * from test where userid having 1 like 1-- RT_userPassword wgf Exceptionjava.sql.DataTruncation: Data truncation .i am not able to understand what type of error is this.